# object props in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6

i have a component that i want to pass a props that is object . i get the data from an api anyway when i pass verificationStatuses directly not work in component and when i manually set values in object it works . both of them are same and when i use console.log for them
object that works is `{__ob__: Observer}` and original object that not working is `{phone:{...}, id_number: {...}}`

and also i set type of props in my component to object

```
    props: {
        verificationFields: Object,
    },
```

what is this weird problem?

```
<verification-statuses-modal :verificationFields="verificationStatuses"/>

                this.verificationStatuses = {
                    id_number:{
                        level: this.verificationStatuses.id_number.level,
                        message: this.verificationStatuses.id_number.message,
                        status: this.verificationStatuses.id_number.status,
                        type: this.verificationStatuses.id_number.type,
                    }, phone:{
                        level: this.verificationStatuses.phone.level,
                        message: this.verificationStatuses.phone.message,
                        status: this.verificationStatuses.phone.status,
                        type: this.verificationStatuses.phone.type,
                    }
                };
```

Comment: Sorry, but your question is very unclear. Can you elaborate it a little bit and maybe add some more code?

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html